# Change column status on "IS NULL" condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, coalesce, isnull

I have a table `tblBooking`:

```
bkID bkCusID bkTotalAmount
---- ------- -------------
17   11      NULL
18   11      NULL
19   11      NULL
```

If `bkTotalAmount` is null then `bkStatus` should be a `0` and if not the it should `1`:

```
bkID bkCusID bkStatus
---- ------- -------------
17   11      
18   11      
19   11
```

I've used `COALESCE` to change the status to `0` but don't know, how to change status to `1` if `bkTotalAmount` is not null:

```
SELECT bkID, bkCusID, COALESCE(bkTotalAmount, 0) AS bkStatus
FROM tblBooking
WHERE bkCusID = 11 AND bkTotalAmount IS NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `case`:

```
SELECT bkID, bkCusID,
       (CASE WHEN bkTotalAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) AS bkStatus
FROM tblBooking
WHERE bkCusID = 11 ;
```

If you want this stored in the table itself, you *could* use an update.  Instead, I would suggest adding a computed column:

```
alter table tblBooking add bkStatus as (CASE WHEN bkTotalAmount IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END);
```

Comment: no need to apply condition `AND bkTotalAmount IS NULL` ?

Comment: @Asif.Ali . . . That seems like an unusual condition of you want the column to ever have a "1".

Answer (score 0):

Use ISNULL function instead of COALESCE

```
SELECT 
bkID,
bkCusID,
ISNULL(bkTotalAmount+1, 0) AS bkStatus 
FROM tblBooking WHERE bkCusID=11
```

Comment: if not null how to add `1` ?